# python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output on python 2.7

Tags: python, pip, installation

I am using python 2.7 with Django. and after I was install `pip install mysqlclient`, I got this error.

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/local/opt/python@2/bin/python2.7 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/tj/vjwl0qpd6l5ct6bdjgwyk1rh0000gp/T/pip-install-QSWu02/MySQL-python/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/tj/vjwl0qpd6l5ct6bdjgwyk1rh0000gp/T/pip-install-QSWu02/MySQL-python/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/tj/vjwl0qpd6l5ct6bdjgwyk1rh0000gp/T/pip-install-QSWu02/MySQL-python/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /private/var/folders/tj/vjwl0qpd6l5ct6bdjgwyk1rh0000gp/T/pip-install-QSWu02/MySQL-python/
    Complete output (10 lines):
    sh: mysql_config: command not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/tj/vjwl0qpd6l5ct6bdjgwyk1rh0000gp/T/pip-install-QSWu02/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "setup_posix.py", line 43, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
      File "setup_posix.py", line 25, in mysql_config
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
    EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: The program `mysql_config` was not found. What exactly is unclear? Probably you need to install it first.